# can we run multiple selenium WebDriver scripts in a single browser?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

can any one suggest me on how to run multiple selenium scripts in a single firefox browser and the webdriver should be initialized only ones and that too in parent class, language used well be java

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `@before` annotation of junit  to `@beforeClass`

example code

```
@BeforeClass
      public  void intialization(String machine) throws Exception {




             driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                baseUrl = "http://"+machine+":8080/";
               driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
                driver.get(baseUrl);
                utilities.Login(driver,"test","1234");
          }
```

How to run other Junit class inside one class please check example below

```
 @Test 
    public void callotherJunitClasses()
    {
    JUnitCore.runClasses(TypeNameofyourClass.class);


    }
```

Comment: hi fahad thanks for ur reply,my thing is in a single browser i want to run multiple class i.e selenium scripts.My request is that how to import the webdriver object from parent class class to child class

Comment: lets say we have 3 classs class A B and C now assume one class whihc is to you parent class call following code to RUN class B and C inside A

Comment: JUnitCore.runClasses(B.class);JUnitCore.runClasses(C.class); in A

Comment: so how to declare web driver variable in class B and class C

Comment: no need to declare webdriver will automatically utilize open instance of firefox by class A try it

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

You can create a framework that uses WebDriver to launch Selenium test-cases. Initialize the driver (ChromeDriver or FirefoxDriver) at runtime once only, and launch the tests sequentially.

For example, if you were using resource bundles, you would have FooTest.java and BarTest.java(your scripts), alongwith FooTest.properties and BarTest.properties, from which you would read the property values eg input-text values.

You might have a Launchpage.properties which has the URL to be launched eg:
`localhost:8080\mypage`
WebDriver would be initialized by the framework at startup, and Launchpage.properties might have the stages to be launched serially.

Whats implicit here is that the browser is opened once only, so the actions of test 2 are dependent on, and must succeed the actions of test 1.

Comment: fahad&threesidedcoin,can we define the Webdriver Variable in parent class as global ,so that it can be accessible(called) from any were in the project  is it possible?

Comment: You could delegate the work to a framework class. for eg in FooTest.java, calling mybutton.click calls click in the framework class which has a reference to Selenium. mybutton is simply an element with some distinguishing feature eg an ID or an XPATH.

Comment: If you have a reference to WebDriver in the parent then yes, it will be inherited by the child.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388940/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-run-multiple-tests-one-after-the-other-in-the-same

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multi-threading concept

1. Initialize Webdriver
2. Create multiple threads and execute it

This will start executing the code parallely on a single browser

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your support query has solved by own.

PackageA-->ClassA:

Intialized the webdriver object in public as..

**"public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();"**

Package B-->ClassB:

calling the WebDriver variable in class B by assiging  to needsx

**import PackageA.ClassA;**

**public static  WebDriver needsX = ClassA.driver;**

so now i can able to access the webdriver variable globally and can run multiple script in a single browser sequentially.