# Browser is opening everytime a new scenario start executing

Tags: cucumber-java

Whenever a new scenario starts executing from my feature file, a new browser is getting started. I want that the browser should only start once when my first scenario executes and for the rest of the scenario a new browser should not open.

I have written my browser opening code into `@Before` annotation under `Hooks` class.

```
@Before(order=1)
public void initialization(Scenario scenario){
log.debug("This is testing for log");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\java\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();

}

My Feature file is as below:

Feature: SignUp Functionality

   @tag1
   Scenario: Verify the SignUp functionality
   Given User is on Home Page
   When User click on the SignUp link
   And Enters signup details
   Then the user should be signed up successfully
   And success message should display

   @tag2
   Scenario: Verify the Login functionality
   Given: User is on the Login page
   When: User enters valid credentials and clicks on the login button
   Then: User should log in successfully and dashboard should display.`
```

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice you should get avoid of it but as an answer there is couple of ways to do it.

First you can use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations to invoke and kill browser beside of `@Before` and `@After` and after that in your before and after annotations you can get the current browser instance.

You can also check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388940/selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-run-multiple-tests-one-after-the-other-in-the-same).